# Splitting labels on multiple lines not working for .dot file used in an Overleaf document

Tags: tikz-pgf, line-breaking, dot2texi

I would like to split a label in a .dot file across multiple lines in Overleaf.

I reviewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841135/newline-in-node-label-in-dot-graphviz-language) which suggests various forms of \n which doesn't seem to work.

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{dot2texi}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{dot2tex}[scale=0.9]
\input{depth.dot}
\end{dot2tex}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here's the depth.dot file

```
digraph Tree {
node [shape=box, fontname="helvetica"] ;
edge [fontname="helvetica"] ;
0 [label="X[1] <= 1.401\nentropy = 0.858\\\nsamples = 227\nvalue = [47, 4, 176]"] ;
1 [label="X[0] <= 1.02\nentropy = 1.191\nsamples = 43\nvalue = [29, 4, 10]"] ;
0 -> 1 [labeldistance=2.5, labelangle=45, headlabel="True"] ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding 'pgf' seems to have fixed it (for some reason), enabling the '\n' to cause newlines in the label.

```
...
\begin{dot2tex}[pgf, scale=0.9]
...
```